# How to get the Google Cloud Run container name using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm very new to GCP, and am working toward deploying a cloud run container. Part of my project will require that I get the name of the container via code in Node.js. Is there a way that I can do this?

I have done a bunch of research, but have not found an answer. As a note, my cloud run container will not auto-scale. There will be only one instance.

```js
const container = require('@google-cloud/container')
let containerName = container.name
```

Comment: You haven't easy way to get the container name (but you can, I can guide you). You can get the service name for instance. Are you sure that you need the name of the package (the container)?

Comment: Actually just realized a bit ago that the container name isn't useful to me. It is the service name that I want. I appreciate the response!

Comment: With that said, the container names are available via environment variable: GAE_INSTANCE. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables. Well, in App Engine, which I ended up going with for my project.

Comment: With Cloud Run, you can get the `K_SERVICE` en var that provide the service name. GAE with containers isn't a solution that I recommend. But if it match your requirement, that's fine. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#env-vars